# Allow Java to recognize input not equal to a wanted value

Tags: java

I am new to both Java and this site so please have mercy on any mistake I may make, I am at my wits end!

I am trying to make a program that calculates the speed of sound through different mediums. As of now the program will ask the user for input on the distance and allow input, same for the medium. I created several cases that will calculate the the answer of the given medium which work properly.

The issue is when I try to create a loop that recognizes if the medium input is not one of the 4 options available. I was able to successfully create a loop that recognizes if the distance input is not a numeric value and tried using similar principles for the medium input but either keep getting stuck in infinite loops or getting the message I created for a wrong entry when I entered the right option.
I have tried the basic loops that I have been taught: for, do-while, etc., but am stuck. Any and all suggestions are appreciated, thank you so much!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //prompt the user about the purpose of this program

    System.out.println(" The purpose of this program is to calculate the speed of sound through several mediums.\n The program user will input a distance in feet followed by a mediums and the program will output the speed in feet per second and miles per hour\n");
    //declare variables

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    final double Air = 1126.1;

    final double Water = 4603.2;

    final double Steel = 20013.3;

    final double Earth = 22967.4;

    double OneFootPerSecond = .68181818182;

    double Distance;

    double AirSpeed;

    double WaterSpeed;

    double SteelSpeed;

    double EarthSpeed;

    System.out.print(" What is the distance in feet:" );
    //ask the user to input variables


        while (!keyboard.hasNextDouble()){
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid numeric value, try again: ");
        keyboard.next();
        }
        Distance =keyboard.nextDouble();
        {
        System.out.print("Input the media: Air, Water, Steel, or Earth: ");
        String Input = keyboard.next();   
        Input.toLowerCase();

        switch (Input)

         {

            case "air":
            AirSpeed = Distance/Air;
            System.out.print("\n \nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through AIR" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f", AirSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Air);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            String Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();

            break;


     case "water":
            WaterSpeed = Distance/Water;
            System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through WATER" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f",WaterSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Water);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
    break;

     case "steel":
            SteelSpeed = Distance/Steel;
            System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through STEEL" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f",SteelSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Steel);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
    break;     

          case "earth":
            EarthSpeed = Distance/Water;
            System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through EARTH" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f",EarthSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Earth);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
    break;
```

Comment: `Input.toLowerCase();` doesn't do anything as it *returns* the lower case of the string. Try `switch(Input.toLowerCase()) {` instead.

Comment: ...or even better, create an Enum that you switch on instead. This means that your switch statement wont ever get messed with by (potential) future programmers. It's a poor example in this case, because you're switching over user input (a String), but do not grow a habit of switching over Strings when you've got Enums available. :)

Comment: Like I said below, I changed the input as suggested which helped, I also added default which also helped. However how do I let the user input the medium an infinite amount of times until the right one is chosen? Edit: and also use the input for one of the cases if it matches?

Comment: You need to read the Java Style Guide: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html .  Variable names should NEVER start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Note taken, it's just a grammatical habit!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as suggested in the comment, change `Input.toLowerCase();` to something like:

```
Input = Input.toLowerCase();
```

or change `switch(Input)` to:

```
switch(Input.toLowerCase())
```

Now to the fun part...

Instead of a case of a new word, add a `default:` block. This will be run, if nothing else is matched.

```
switch (Input)

    {

        case "air":
            AirSpeed = Distance/Air;
            System.out.print("\n \nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through AIR" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f", AirSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Air);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            String Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();
        break;


        // Some more cases...


        default:
            // Something something that will happen as a "last resort".

        break;

  } // End switch
```

Comment: I changed the input as suggested which helped, I also added default which also helped. However how do I let the user input the medium an infinite amount of times until the right one is chosen? Edit: and also use the input for one of the cases if it matches?

Comment: @user2824855: You could use a while loop that loops as long as a `boolean quitLoop` is not true. This could be set to true, if the user enters "quit" instead of "air" or any of the other possibilities. You could then set up a case that matches "quit", and sets `quitLoop` to `true`. When the switch breaks, and the loop restarts, `quitLoop` will be `true`, which means `!quitLoop` will be `false`, and the loop will end.

Answer (score 0):

No problem.

I see the following Problem:

`Input.toLowerCase();`

is not working use

`Input=Input.toLowerCase();`

because the function just return a new String